# gotoAndPlay not working! AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

Thank you for looking at my post. So I was going to make an AIR for Android game, so I got to work, and, well heres the problem.

```
stop();

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

btn_Play.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler_2);

function fl_TapHandler_2(event: TouchEvent): void

{

gotoAndPlay(91);

}
```

When ever I tap the btn_Play, it just goes to Frame 1 and plays. BTW this is on Frame 90. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

if you have only `90` frames and you define

```
gotoAndPlay(91);
```

you will go to frame `1`, change to:

```
gotoAndPlay(90);
```

if you have more than 90 frames probably you need to read this:

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?335765-gotoAndPlay%28%29-and-frame-script-stop%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrote stop() method at end of the frame? if not try this at end of the frame or how many frames are you using kindly check that.

```
stop()
```